# Java 8 Group by and append to a set

Tags: java, collections, java-8, group-by, collectors

I have function which returns a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, Code before java 8:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> degreeMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Course  course : courses){
    Set<String> cList = degreeMap.get(course.getCourseLevel().toString());
    if(Objects.nonNull(cList)){
        cList.addAll(course.getMasterDegree()); //this is what i want to append to the old set
        degreeMap.put(course.getCourseLevel().toString(), cList);
    } else{
        degreeMap.put(course.getCourseLevel().toString(), new HashSet<>(course.getMasterDegree()));
    }
} 
return degreeMap;
```

Which return a map of courselevel -> set of degrees.

For example, it read all the courses and return a map like:

```
{"undergraduate" : ["BTech", "BSc", "BE"],
"masters": ["MTech", "MBA"],
"Executive": ["PGDBM", "EECP"]}
```

Here is my Course class:

```
public class Course {
    private List<String> masterDegree;
    private CourseLevel courseLevel;
}
```

But I want to write this piece of code in Java 8 style. For that, I tried this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> degreeMap = courses.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getCourseLevel().toString(),
                Collectors.mapping(c -> c.getMasterDegree(), Collectors.toSet()))
);
```

which is not working and I am getting the following compile-time error on this:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that List conforms to String inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: String lower bounds: List

Any suggestion, how to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds to me that you're looking for a [`flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) equivalent of Java-9 in an older version.

Comment: @GhostCat tried editing the question to be relevant enough. hope its clear now.

Comment: @Naman thanks for resolving this battle :P

Comment: `for(Course  course : courses) degreeMap.computeIfAbsent(course.getCourseLevel() .toString(), x -> new HashSet<>()) .addAll(course.getMasterDegree());` By the way, even in your pre-Java 8 version, there never was a reason to `put` the same list into the `Map` again after `addAll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but looks like, you're looking for something like:

```
    return courses.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(course -> course.getCourseLevel().toString(),
                    course -> new HashSet<>(course.getMasterDegree()),
                    (set1, set2) -> Stream.of(set1, set2)
                            .flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: In this case, `(set1, set2) -> { set1.addAll(set2); return set1; }` clearly is the preferable merge function…

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the Collectors.toMap() method.

Here is an example that you may need to tweak as I did not test it.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> degreeMap = courses.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            item -> item.getCourseLevel().toString(), //your key mapping
            item -> item.getMasterDegree(), //your value mapping
            (oldValue, newValue) -> { //your process of aggregation
                if (null == oldValue) {
                    return newValue;
                } else {
                    oldValue.addAll(newValue);
                    return oldValue;
                }
            },
            LinkedHashMap::new //your result initialiser
        )
    );
```

Also, another tip: you do not need to get by key and check for null, you can use the .compute(), .computeIfAbsent(), .computeIfPresent() methods on the map

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need lamda expression, you should refactor your codes to make it clear instead.

```
        // supposed to be initialied with non-empty values
        // Map<String, Set<String>> degreeMap = ...

        for(Course  course : courses){
            // something like below
            String key = course.getCourseLevel().toString();
            // degreeSet should not be null
            Set<String> degreeSet = course.getMasterDegree();

            // TODO: check nullable
            degreeSet.putAll(degreeMap.get(key));

            degreeMap.put(key, degreeSet);
        } 

        return degreeMap;
```